# Bootstrap collapse all accordions on button click

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to collapse/expand all accordions with a button click?
I tried it with a simple button that removeClass active and addClass active but it did not work at all. I can only open them all up at once but not collapse again and then open up again.

my current button :

```
$("#collapseAll").click( function() {
    $(".accordion-header").removeClass("active").addClass("active");
});
```

my js:

```
$('.js-accordion dt, .js-toggle').on('click tap', function(){
    $($(this).data('target') ? $(this).data('target') : $(this)).toggleClass('active');
});
```

and my html

```
<dl class="accordion js-accordion" data-toggle="accordion-header">
    {{#each accordion}}
    <div id="{{anchor}}-div">
        <dt class="accordion-header{{#if active}} active{{/if}}">
            <h3 class="accordion-item-title"{{#if anchor}} id="{{anchor}}"{{/if}}>{{{title}}}</h3>
            <span class="accordion-item-icon"></span>
        </dt>
        <dd class="accordion-body">
            <div class="accordion-item-content">
                {{#if textblock}}
                    {{#each textblock}}
                        <p>{{{.}}}</p>
                    {{/each}}
                {{/if}}
                <p>{{#if anchor}}<a href="#{{anchor}}" class="faq-anchor">{{../../page-contents.section-main.texts.permalink}}</a>{{/if}}</p>
                <p><a href="#top">{{../../page-contents.section-main.texts.to_top}}</a></p>
            </div>
        </dd>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by myself with this code

```
$("#collapseAll").click( function() {
        let button = document.getElementById("collapseAll");
        if(!$('.accordion-header').hasClass("active")){
            $('.accordion-header').removeClass("active").addClass("active");
            button.innerHTML = 'Collapse all'

        } else {
            $('.accordion-header').addClass("active").removeClass("active");
            button.innerHTML = 'Expand all'
        }
    });
```

also with changing button text!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it like this

[Repo Github](https://github.com/Dominikg77/AccordionCollapsAllFromButton)

```js
function toggleAllAccordions() {
  var button = document.getElementById("collapseAll");
  var accordionHeaders = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-header button");
  var accordionCollapses = document.querySelectorAll(".accordion-collapse");

  var isCollapsed = Array.from(accordionHeaders).some(function (header) {
    return !header.classList.contains("collapsed");
  });

  if (isCollapsed) {
    button.innerHTML = "Expand all";
    accordionHeaders.forEach(function (header) {
      header.classList.add("collapsed");
    });
    accordionCollapses.forEach(function (collapse) {
      collapse.classList.remove("show");
    });
  } else {
    button.innerHTML = "Collaps all";
    accordionHeaders.forEach(function (header) {
      header.classList.remove("collapsed");
    });
    accordionCollapses.forEach(function (collapse) {
      collapse.classList.add("show");
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Bootstrap 5 Accordions mit Toggle-Button</title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="mt-5 container">
      <div>
        <button
          id="collapseAll"
          onclick="toggleAllAccordions()"
          class="btn btn-primary mb-3"
          style="width: 200px"
        >
          Collaps all
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
            <button
              class="accordion-button"
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#collapseOne"
              aria-expanded="false"
            >
              Accordion Item #1
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div
            id="collapseOne"
            class="accordion-collapse collapse show"
            aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
          >
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is
              shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate
              classes that we use to style each element. These classes control
              the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS
              transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
              overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just
              about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>,
              though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
            <button
              class="accordion-button collapsed"
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#collapseTwo"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-controls="collapseTwo"
            >
              Accordion Item #2
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div
            id="collapseTwo"
            class="accordion-collapse collapse"
            aria-labelledby="headingTwo"
            data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"
          >
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is
              hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate
              classes that we use to style each element. These classes control
              the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS
              transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
              overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just
              about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>,
              though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-item">
          <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
            <button
              class="accordion-button collapsed"
              type="button"
              data-bs-toggle="collapse"
              data-bs-target="#collapseThree"
              aria-expanded="false"
              aria-controls="collapseThree"
            >
              Accordion Item #3
            </button>
          </h2>
          <div
            id="collapseThree"
            class="accordion-collapse collapse"
            aria-labelledby="headingThree"
            data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"
          >
            <div class="accordion-body">
              <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is
              hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate
              classes that we use to style each element. These classes control
              the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS
              transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or
              overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just
              about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>,
              though the transition does limit overflow.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).